# PHP 7.1 | Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in

Tags: functions, theme-development, ajax

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in line 107.

```
<div class="like">
    <?php 
        $nonce = wp_create_nonce("my_user_vote_nonce");
        $likeLink = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=my_user_vote&custom=like&post_id='.$post->ID.'&nonce='.$nonce);            
    ?>
    <a class="like" data-image="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/loading.gif" data-field="like" data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>" data-post_id="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" href="<?php echo $link ?>" title="Like"><span><?php echo number_format(get_post_meta($post->ID, "like", true) * 1, 0, ',', '.'); ?></span></a>
</div>
```

line 107

```
<a class="like" data-image="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/loading.gif" data-field="like" data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>" data-post_id="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" href="<?php echo $link ?>" title="Like"><span><?php echo number_format(get_post_meta($post->ID, "like", true) * 1, 0, ',', '.'); ?></span></a>
```

Comment: You have a lot of stuff on that line, can you split it into multiple lines so that we can figure out which part is the problem? I have a suspicion where it is. Otherwise, are you asking where the warning is, what the warning means, or are you asking how to fix it?

Comment: Thank you Tom for your help, i want to fix it. Why it is happening with PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is this:

```php
echo number_format(get_post_meta($post->ID, "like", true) * 1, 0, ',', '.')
```

Here, we take the post meta named `like` and multiply it by 1, but what if that post meta doesn't contain a number? What if it contains something else?

For example, if we did `2 x 4`, we would expect PHP to give us 8, which is correct, but what if we tell PHP to multiple `2 x "hello"`? or  `-` ? When that happens PHP will throw a warning, the same one that you are encountering.

So first, don't just smush everything on to one line, use a variable to store the post meta output:

```php
$like = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "like", true );
```

Then use that variable instead:

```php
echo number_format($likes, 0, ',', '.')
```

Now that we've done that, it's possible to check and format the variable as a number:

```php
if ( !is_numeric( $likes ) ) {
    $likes = 0;
}
```

So if `$likes` is a `false` or an error value, we set it to `0` rather than just blindly using it and hoping for the best.

And finally, that line has a lot of things going on, so this might not be the issue causing the warning at all, it's not possible to tell. In future instead of:

```php
    <a class="like" data-image="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/loading.gif" data-field="like" data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>" data-post_id="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" href="<?php echo $link ?>" title="Like"><span><?php echo number_format(get_post_meta($post->ID, "like", true) * 1, 0, ',', '.'); ?></span></a>
```

Do:

```php
    <a
        class="like"
        data-image="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/loading.gif"
        data-field="like"
        data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>"
        data-post_id="<?php echo $post->ID ?>"
        href="<?php echo $link ?>"
        title="Like"
    >
        <span>
            <?php echo number_format(get_post_meta($post->ID, "like", true) * 1, 0, ',', '.'); ?>
        </span>
    </a>
```

*The above snippet does not contain any fixes, but, it's easier to read, and easier to debug, taking all the guesswork out of which part of the line has the problem.*

Comment: It worked flawlessly ! Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it working :) If this answers your question can you mark it as the correct answer? It's the big tick just under the voting arrows to the left of the answer